# Making sure Integer.parseInt(String) is a valid int in java

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to get some basic info about a user, such as height, weight, ect.

I am using EditText objects and `getText()` to retrieve the text from what the user has typed. Then I convert that to a string, and finally convert everything to an int using `Integer.parseint(String)`. Below is an example of what I am attempting to do if that was confusing.

```
if((height.getText().length() > 0) && (???)) {
    mHeight = Integer.parseInt(height.getText().toString());
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter your height, in inches, rounded to the nearest inch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    canContinue = -1;
}
```

I used `height.getText().length() > 0` to make sure that the user has at least put something into the field, but if the user puts characters, then the program crashes.

The (???) is the assertion I am trying to complete here, that will return a false when the result isn't a valid int. Also note that I initialized mHeight as a primitive int here `int mHeight`

**Note**: height is an `EditText` object and I initialized it like so: `height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);`

Comment: Put a `try/catch` around your `Integer.parseInt` so you can catch the exception if it can't be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `height.getText().matches("\\d+")` to check if that is a number only

like:

```
if((height.getText().length() > 0) && height.getText().toString().matches("\\d+")) {

}
```

Comment: I know, nothing will beat the ***Integer.parseInt()*** but OP intention is to discard alpha char sequences before trying to parse...

Comment: Would making the height.getText() into a string using toString() before using matches() work? The height.getText() isn't a string so using matches on it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Short of doing some complicated validations, I would simply try to parse and catch any exceptions.

```
//test that the value is not empty and only contains numbers
//to deal with most common errors
if(!height.getText().isEmpty() && height.getText().matches("\\d+")) {
  try {
    mHeight = Integer.parseInt(height.getText());
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) { //will be thrown if number is too large
    //error handling
  }
}
```

Comment: Is a try catch necessary here if I throw away everything that isn't an int or null?

Comment: No, but how do you know that the text is an int? For example, 10000000000 is NOT an int (too big).

Answer (score 1):

Write the following method and call it instead of "???"

```
    public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
    {  
      try  
      {  
        int d = Integer.parseInt(str);  
      }  
      catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
      {  
        return false;  
      }  
      return true;  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try parsing it an catch any exceptions:-

```
try {
    int mHeight = 0;
    if (height.getText().length() > 0) {
        mHeight = Integer.parseInt(height.getText().toString());
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter your height, in inches, rounded to the nearest inch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    canContinue = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to get numbers add inputType attribute to your EditText

like

```
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

then users can only enter numbers into the EditText,hence no error while parsing it.